# How to post antiforgery token with content security policy report

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, content-security-policy, antiforgerytoken

In my ASP.NET MVC application i have implemented custom AntiForgeryToken attribute that validates every POST request for AntiForgeryToken. This way i do not have to add `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute on each action method, instead it is handled globally for all POST requests.

Recently i have enabled content security policy for my web application. CSP looks like below

```
default-src 'none' https:; 
script-src 'self'; 
style-src 'self';
img-src 'self' data:; 
font-src 'self'; 
report-uri /csp/report;
```

Browser POST the violation report to `/csp/report` url, but without anti-forgery token, hence my global anti-forgery validation fails.

In `_layout.cshtml` page i am creating token as `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`. So token is created for every view.

When browser POST csp-report, is there anyway to tell browser to also post anti-forgery token if its available in DOM?

*right now just to get it working, i have updated my Anti-forgery validation logic to skip validation for `/csp/report/` url.*

**Update 1**

```
public class ValidatePostAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    private const string _tokenKey = "__RequestVerificationToken";
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {                    
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get(AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName) == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpPostAntiForgeryException("Invalid Verification Cookie.");
                }
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Get(_tokenKey) == null)
                {
                    throw new HttpPostAntiForgeryException("Invalid Verification Token.");
                }

                AntiForgery.Validate(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName].Value, filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers[_tokenKey]);
            }
            else
            {
                // dont validate post for content security policy report
                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToLower().Contains("csp/report"))
                {
                    return;
                }

                // validate non ajax POST
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find  way to do what you were asking about? I'm hitting the same issue.

Comment: no. i am skipping for the csp report. See my update 1